# Same stylesheet is displayed differently on browser and on server where its stored

Tags: css, caching, stylesheet

Today I've got a very weird issue when editing my CSS stylesheet. I've got a VPS running on Debian and website ran via Nginx. Forum is ran on MyBB and I just setup Cloudflare there.

So basically, earlier today I edited my stylesheet and it didn't apply to my website. I checked it via Inspect on Google Chrome to see what stylesheet it actually loads. It turned out that it loads the same stylesheet but it is displayed different when accessed via browser than this same file is displayed on the server. So pretty much each time I update the stylesheet, the one on the server is updated but the one that is loaded (this same CSS file) remains unchanged.

Could you please assist me with that? Not very experienced person here but got some common knowledge, which unfortunately doesn't help me solve this issue though.

(Tried cleaning browser cache and accessing via other devices, result is the same)

Comment: Which browser do you use where?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like the server is caching the stylesheet as well.

Check and see if your VPS provider has a way for you to turn off server caching through their admin panel.

Answer (score 0):

Turning on CloudFlare developer mode fixed the issue :)

Comment: You can try purging cache on CloudFlare.